# Pygame pygame.Rect.clamp

Tags: pygame

I can't get `clamp` to work. I thought `clamp` is to keep a rect inside of another, however the following try doesn't put the blue ball inside the red rect. Where is the problem?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

TV=pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Rect")

c=pygame.draw.circle(TV,(0,100,0),(150,100),100,1)
c1=pygame.draw.circle(TV,(0,0,200),(250,250),20,1)
r=pygame.draw.rect(TV,(100,0,0),c,1)
c1.clamp(r)
pygame.display.flip()


while True:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
```

Comment: a `circle` returns a `Rect`

Answer (score 2):

`clamp` returns a new `Rect` without changing the source `Rect` itself.

If you want to change the source `Rect`, you'll have to use [`clamp_ip`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clamp_ip).

But this is not enough for you, because you draw the circle directly on the screen surface, and changing the resultung `Rect` does nothing:

You have to create a new `Surface`, draw your circle onto it and get a `Rect` from that `Surface` (or any other Rect you're going to use for drawing, but it's easiest to just use the `get_rect()` function).

Then do whatever you want with that `Rect`, e.g. use `clamp_ip` or get a new one with `clamp`, then use that `Rect` (or the new one) together with the [`blit`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) function, e.g. `TV.blit(the_new_surface, the_rect)`.